# how do I align span text at exactly center from top and bottom covered by the main text. It's placed at the button

Tags: html, css

As mentioned, How do I center the span wrt the main text? It's placed at the center so if I can place it at the exactly the center. This is the price card and I added a small text after the main text so the span is smaller than the main text and it needs to fit at the center.

```
<html>
        <head>
        
        <style>
        
        h1{
          font-size:30px;
        }
        
        span{
          font-size:15px;
          text-decoration:line-through;
          align-items:center;
          justify-content:center;
        }
        
        </style>
        
        </head>
        
        <body>
        
        h1{
          font-size:30px;
        }
        
        span{
          font-size:15px;
          text-decoration:line-through;
        }
        </body>
        
        </html>
```

Comment: you need to edit your code, you put your css inside the body.

Answer (score 0):

Add display: flex in span selector.
Remove css inside the body.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).